# Send a azure queue message in a docker container to a queue triggered function in another docker container

Tags: docker-compose, azure-functions, azure-queues, docker-network, azurite

It is really difficult to explain. I am not expert in docker. I will try it.

I have 3 components:

1. 1 container with Azurite
2. 1 container with a queue function
3. Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer in the host.

I am using docker-compose.yml to reach my goal.

After two day I could configure correctly the Azurite container to communicate correctly with the Storage Explorer in the host. Here the portion of code in my composer file:

```
services:
  storage:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    container_name: storage
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7777:10000
      - 8888:10001
      - 9999:10002   
    environment: 
      - "AZURITE_ACCOUNTS=devnotificationsstorage:Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="
    command: "azurite -l /workspace -d /workspace/debug.log --blobPort 10000 --blobHost 0.0.0.0 --queuePort 10001 --queueHost 0.0.0.0 --tablePort 10002 --tableHost 0.0.0.0"
    volumes: 
      - "./datadir/azurite:/workspace"
```

I mapped the port `7777` in my host with the port `10000` of the container with Azurite. I cannot use the port `10000` in my host because it is already used by Storage Explorer with another local container. However I find strange that everything works setting port 8888 on the host. Here a screen of Sotrage Explorer:

[image]

Surely I haven'y understood something.

In any case, now I can correctly insert the message in the containerized queue from the Storage Explorer.
But when I insert the message in the queue I expect to receive the message on the queue container. I let you see the whole compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  storage:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    container_name: storage
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7777:10000
      - 8888:10001
      - 9999:10002   
    environment: 
      - "AZURITE_ACCOUNTS=devnotificationsstorage:Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="
    command: "azurite -l /workspace -d /workspace/debug.log --blobPort 10000 --blobHost 0.0.0.0 --queuePort 10001 --queueHost 0.0.0.0 --tablePort 10002 --tableHost 0.0.0.0"
    volumes: 
      - "./datadir/azurite:/workspace"
    networks:
      - shared_network

  xxx.notifications.azurefunction.emails:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}xxxgonotificationsazurefunctionemails
    container_name: notifications_email
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: XXX.Notifications.AzureFunction.Emails/Dockerfile
    depends_on: 
      - storage  
    networks:
      - shared_network

networks:
  shared_network:
```

And here the `localhost.settings.json` file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "StorageConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

Please, note that if I send a message from local queue on port `10000` (the non-dockerized queue), I receive the message on the queue triggered function.
But if I send the queue from the dockerized queue nothing happend.

I also thought that perhpas, the connection string is wrong. So I changed the `StorageConnectionString` with the value I see in the Storage explorer. That is the new `localhost.settings.json` file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "StorageConnectionString": "AccountName=devnotificationsstorage;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:7777/devnotificationsstorage;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:8888/devnotificationsstorage;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:9999/devnotificationsstorage;"
  }
}
```

In this case, when I write a message on the dockerized queue (and just when I write the message on the queue), I get this error:

> Azure.Core: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:8888). System.Net.Http: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:8888). System.Net.Sockets: Connection refused.

How do I have to configure my containers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This connection string is wrong:

`"StorageConnectionString": "AccountName=devnotificationsstorage;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:7777/devnotificationsstorage;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:8888/devnotificationsstorage;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:9999/devnotificationsstorage;"`

I must replace the host `127.0.0.1` and the ports with the ones I defined for my container.

First of all, the host. We can use the same name we used to define the container in the compose. In my case `storage` (second line):

```
services:
  storage: <-- This is thehost name
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    container_name: storage
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7777:10000
      - 8888:10001
      - 9999:10002   
    environment: 
      - "AZURITE_ACCOUNTS=devnotificationsstorage:Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="
    command: "azurite -l /workspace -d /workspace/debug.log --blobPort 10000 --blobHost 0.0.0.0 --queuePort 10001 --queueHost 0.0.0.0 --tablePort 10002 --tableHost 0.0.0.0"
    volumes: 
      - "./datadir/azurite:/workspace"
    networks:
      - shared_network
```

Second I mapped the ports of my service in this way:

```
    ports:
      - 7777:10000
      - 8888:10001
      - 9999:10002
```

That means `host:container`. So every Http message sent on port `8888` of the host (in the context of Docker) will be received on port `10001` in my container.

So if I have to check if there are messages in the queue of my container I must change the connection string in this way:

`"StorageConnectionString": "AccountName=devnotificationsstorage;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://storage:10000/devnotificationsstorage;QueueEndpoint=http://storage:10001/devnotificationsstorage;TableEndpoint=http://storage:10002/devnotificationsstorage;"`

Comment: thanks very much for this! It put me on the right track and helped solve my problem. I was having a hard time getting this right for a similar set up. Turns out my client's connection string was also incorrect and should have had `http://container:10001`  instead of `http://127.0.0.1:10001`. I dunno, perhaps the Azurite docs could make this clearer? Or perhaps I just have a fundamental lack of understanding of how Docker works which is entirely possible.